# Broken pipe (os error 32) al iniciar zsh

Tags: git, zsh

Estoy iniciando en el mundo linux. Estoy usando ubuntu en WSL2 y al iniciar mi terminal con zsh no carga el tema Starship y marca el error:

```
(eval):source:1: no such file or directory: /proc/self/fd/13source
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed printing to stdout: Broken pipe (os error 32)', library/std/src/io/stdio.rs:1019:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Lo que creo que tuvo que ver fue que yo al no saber inglés a la hora de instalar el pluging zsh-syntax-highlighting accidentalmente ejecute el comando incorrecto de instalación que es:

```
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git
echo "source ${(q-)PWD}/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc
```

En vez de `git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting` porque uso oh-my-zsh.
Pero que este comando incorrecto sea el origen del problema es una suposición por ahora. ¿Podrían decirme cómo corregirlo?

Comment: Creo que sería conveniente que imprimieras el contenido de este archivo en la pregunta: `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshrc`